# Reading number from txt file, add some it with some number & then rewrite it to a different file in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, file-handling, do-while

i am making a billing system for practice and there is a option where previous sale will display.(read previous sale from file if exist, add it with new sale with previous sale and write on txt file).i have try it but there is some logical error. kindly help me as soon as possible.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int choice,sale,pre_sale,t_sale;
    ifstream saleFilein;
    ofstream saleFileout;
    do
    {
        cout<<"1 : Enter new sale\n"
          <<"2 : View previous sale\n"
          <<"3 : Exit\n";
        cin>>choice;

        if(choice==1)
        {
            system("cls");
            cout<<"Enter the sale: ";
            cin>>sale;
            saleFileout.open("testsale.txt");

            saleFilein.open("testsale.txt");
            saleFilein>>pre_sale;
            saleFilein.close();
            sale+=pre_sale;
            saleFileout<<sale;
            saleFileout.close();
        }
        else if(choice==2)
        {
            saleFilein.open("testsale.txt");
            saleFilein>>t_sale;
            saleFilein.close();
            cout<<"THE PREVIOUS SALE IS"<<t_sale;
        }
    }
    while(choice<3);
}
```

Comment: sale is not correctly showing.when new sale is added.

Comment: maybe some indent? Also show us an example of input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `main` will work as expected:

```
int main()
{
    int choice,sale,pre_sale,t_sale;
    //ifstream saleFilein;
    //ofstream saleFileout;
    do
    {
        cout<<"1 : Enter new sale\n"
          <<"2 : View previous sale\n"
          <<"3 : Exit\n";
        cin>>choice;

        if(choice==1)
        {
            system("cls");
            cout<<"Enter the sale: ";
            cin>>sale;

            ifstream saleFilein("testsale.txt");
            assert(saleFilein);
            saleFilein>>pre_sale;
            if (!saleFilein)
                pre_sale = 0;
            saleFilein.close();

            ofstream saleFileout("testsale.txt");
            sale+=pre_sale;
            saleFileout<<sale;
            saleFileout.close();
        }
        else if(choice==2)
        {
            ifstream saleFilein("testsale.txt");
            saleFilein>>t_sale;

            if (saleFilein)
                cout<<"THE PREVIOUS SALE IS "<<t_sale<<endl;
            else
                cout<<"No previous sale"<<endl;

            saleFilein.close();
        }
    }
    while(choice<3);

    return 0;
}
```

You had a minor problem in not validating the input when the file was missing. But the major one seems related to the strange internal error state flags of the stream: it seems they are still there after closing a stream and kept active by future open operations. To solve the last issue I preferred to simplify the code and localize the use of the stream variables. I can change the code back if it is a must, but it is more `C++` like this way.

Comment: sorry brother i can not understand :(.can you explain it in simple one.

Comment: :)), I don't know what do you don't understand. The above code should work for you, does it?

Comment: its work thanks for helping me.and i am asking about assert()

Comment: You can eliminate the 'assert', it's there just for helping the debugging. It doesn't change the program flow.

Comment: and whats the logic behind the following.

Comment: saleFilein>>pre_sale;
            if (!saleFilein)
                pre_sale = 0;
            saleFilein.close();  can u explain it.

Comment: `if (!saleFilein)` means using `operator!` for the stream: is the stream loaded correctly? did the last read succeeded? If not, then ignore `pre_sale` value (by making it 0).